# Can the iPad detect the shape of a contact on its screen using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

For example, could the iPad or iPhone accurately detect the difference between conductive pieces of plastic in the following shapes using Objective C...

http://i52.tinypic.com/307rtar.gif
http://i51.tinypic.com/23k83tj.gif
http://i55.tinypic.com/nybc6e.gif

---

If the above can't work is it possible to detect the number of points touching the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mr. Weinberg notes, you can't do it with FLAT touches. But, if you put small nubs on the pieces you could use them to stand in for a multi-touch (ie one small nub at each vertex).  You could then figure out the shape of the convex hull these points would create.

Comment: This is along the lines of my thinking after reading Joshua's answer (see my edit to the question)

Comment: agreed, since the API's give us touches you can easily get the difference by introducing touch-points (which you would then get through the API in the form of a touches array with coordinates).

Comment: Further to this, someone has a system in the works involving an iPad board game using physical pieces; the idea is that the iPad knows which piece is which due to the pattern of "nubs" on its base. One article about it, from a quick Google: http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/ipad-iphone-tactile-object-recognition-system-bodes-well-for-board-games-20100827/

Comment: Thanks for that Josh - Someone has clearly pipped me to the post!

Answer (score 3):

The hardware itself might have the ability, but as far as the API we get, no, you wouldn't be able to tell those apart.

To take into account your edit. Yes, you can detect up to 11 discrete touches on the device. From there you should be able to figure out which shape is what pretty easily, but once you have more than 11 contact points on the screen all bets are off.